# Hidden mystery link on new revision history layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, revisions-list

There is a mystery hidden link present on the new revision layout (nice btw):

[image: link mystery?]

It only is present on the first revision.

It does not lead to unicorns :-(. It leads to the same place as the `link` link above it.

Comment: Oops, this'll be removed in the next build. The link link is now a text link in the row of links above. Link.

Comment: @Emmett: It's not removed; it's has been given an icon now instead. And as you say, there is already a link link as a text link in the links row above the now-iconed link link.. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain icon link is gone now, and was replaced with a plain text *link*
 link above.

Comment: I see the new link link, the extra link icon link is now an ex-link!